# Verify form field with isset()

Tags: php

Having issues with verifying that my form fields are not empty. I thought I used isset in the past but I am having issues with it below. I know I can do it with =="" but want to figure it out this way.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$error= false;
 if (isset($_POST['name'])){$name=$_POST['name'];}else{$error=true; $error_message="enter a name"; echo "no name";};

     if(!$error){
                //SUBMIT TO DATABASE
      }else{  echo $error_message;
      }

}
```

But I keep getting the error that error_message is not set.

Comment: Your code indenting could use some work.

Comment: (small note) maybe you want to look at this, for form submit security : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709555/form-security-discussion

Comment: when I use  if ($_POST['name'] == ""){$name=$_POST['name'];}else{$error=FALSE; $error_message="enter a name"; echo "no name";};   error_message is still not getting set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Isset() just test if the variable exists. It's almost always the case in a POST form (even if variable is empty). To be sure they're not, use the empty() test.
Here is the code :

```
if(count($_POST) > 0){
    $error = false;
    if (!empty($_POST['name']))
        $name = $_POST['name'];
    else{
        $error = true;
        $error_message = "enter a name";
        echo "no name";
    }
    if(!$error)
        //SUBMIT TO DATABASE
    else
        echo $error_message;
}
```

you also had a syntax error with the semicolon after your first else.
Be careful, a variable set to 0 is detected as being empty. Check http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Comment: Thanks I will start to use this method.

Answer (score 1):

First, I'd recommend -not- using this method to determine if there was a post. I generally use one of the following:

```
if($_POST)
```

OR

```
if(count($_POST) > 0)
```

The second isset() call (to check for the name) is fine. Try using full caps to set TRUE or FALSE to the $error variable. You can also use 0 and 1 for TRUE and FALSE respectively; they work fine with if($error) and if(!$error). I believe this is where your problem lies. That is, $error was never set properly, so it is in fact not TRUE, but 'false'. However, because $_POST['name'] wasn't set, and $error_message was not either. Let me know if this works for you. I'll look into it further if it doesn't.

Comment: `true` is the exact same thing as `TRUE`, but IMO more readable. `0` and `1` on the other hand are **not** the same as `true` and `false`, don't use them interchangeably!

Answer (score 1):

An empty PHP string is not null:

```
$a = '';
echo isset($a); //true
echo $a == ''; //true
```

use `==` instead

You could also use `empty($var)` function